Balance calculation problem with Foreign Exchange in Mysql
I am trying to make a current balance system for pre-accounting in mysql. I create receipts in different currencies and collect payments in different currencies. My main currency is Turkish Lira (TRY). The amount field in the table below is the amount of the foreign currency itself. I am trying to make my calculations using dovizKarsiligiTl.
yes I missed it
Original table



id
meblag
dovizKuru
dovizKarsiligi
dovizID




452
-60
32,31
1938,63
2


455
100
35,14
3514
3


456
-300
1
300
1






dovizID
name




1
TRY


2
USD


3
EURO



SET @TRY_balance := 0;
SET @USD_balance := 0;
SET @EUR_balance := 0;




id
amount
foreignExchangeEquivalentTl
exchange rate
dovizID
TRY_balance
USD_balance
EUR_balance




452
-60
1938.63
32.31
2
0
1938.6
0


455
100
3514.00
35.14
3
0
1938.6
3514


456
-300
300
1
1
-300
1938.6
3514



In the table above, the TRY_BAKİYE, USD_BAKİYE, EUR_BAKİYE fields are virtual, that is, they can change depending on the transaction we perform in each row.
The table above is now my raw table and my balance fields are incorrect according to my query result.

In line 1, I owe 1938.6 TL, equivalent to -60 dollars.
In the 2nd line, I paid 3514 TL for 100 euros, so according to the balance status of the 2nd line, my debt should have been completed and 1575.4 TL should have become a creditor.
In the 3rd line, I owed 300 TL in return for -300 TL, and since I was credited with 1575.4 TL in the 2nd line, I should have become a creditor of 1275.4 TL. Accordingly, the following table should be formed. However, I cannot find the query that will create this table.




id
amount
exchange rate
dovizID
TRY_balance
USD_balance
EUR_balance




452
-60
32.31
2
0
1938.6
0


455
100
35.14
3
0
0
1575.4


456
-300
1
1
0
0
1275.4



The data here is not fixed but variable. Payment or debt status can be understood from the -+ value in the amount. A positive TL value is kept as the foreign currency equivalent in each line.
I tried making inquiries with Chatgpt for 8 hours, but I did not get any successful results.
My incorrect query is below
SELECT
id,
meblag,
dovizKuru,
dovizKarsiligi,
dovizID,
SUM( CASE WHEN dovizID = 1 THEN CASE WHEN meblag > 0 THEN @TRY_bakiye:= @TRY_bakiye + dovizKarsiligi ELSE @TRY_bakiye := @TRY_bakiye -1*dovizKarsiligi END ELSE 0 END ) OVER (ORDER BY islemTarihi asc ) AS trb,

SUM( CASE WHEN dovizID = 2 THEN CASE WHEN meblag > 0 THEN @USD_bakiye:= @USD_bakiye + @EUR_bakiye + @TRY_bakiye + dovizKarsiligi ELSE @USD_bakiye:= @USD_bakiye:= -1*dovizKarsiligi END ELSE 0 END ) OVER (ORDER BY islemTarihi asc ) AS usb,

SUM( CASE WHEN dovizID = 3 THEN CASE WHEN meblag > 0 THEN @EUR_bakiye:= @EUR_bakiye + dovizKarsiligi ELSE @EUR_bakiye:=@EUR_bakiye -1*dovizKarsiligi END ELSE 0 END ) OVER (ORDER BY islemTarihi asc ) AS eub

FROM
    al_islemler 
WHERE
    al_islemler.cariID = 33 
    AND al_islemler.firmaID = 382 
GROUP BY
    id 
ORDER BY
    al_islemler.islemTarihi ASC,
    al_islemler.id DESC 
    LIMIT 0,
    10;

sample image
my software

it is from you dqata impossible to know what is Dollar or euros in your transaction

yes I missed it
dovizID
1 -> TRY
2 -> USD
3 -> EURO

also why is balance us not negative  also do you have mysql 8 by chance?

I visualized the tables a little more. Is there anything missing for help?

see my last comment

yes there is mysql 8,
The foreign exchange system did not exist before, I am adding it recently. That's why my amount column keeps negative and positive records, while my TL in foreign currency field is only positive. If my amount column is negative in the calculations, I convert my TL field in foreign exchange to negative on the query.

mixing userdefined variables with window functions is niot a good idea

MySQL 8 introduced window functions, which come here very handy
SELECT * 
  , 
  SUM(CASE WHEN dovizID =1 THEN  `amount` * `exchange rate` ELSE 0  END) OVER (ORDER BY `id`) as  `TRY_balance`,
   SUM(CASE WHEN dovizID =2 THEN  `amount` * `exchange rate` ELSE 0 END ) OVER (ORDER BY `id`) AS `USD_balance`,
   SUM(CASE WHEN dovizID =3 THEN  `amount` * `exchange rate` ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY `id`) AS  `EUR_balance` 
  
  FROM balance




id
amount
foreignExchangeEquivalentTl
exchange rate
dovizID
TRY_balance
USD_balance
EUR_balance




452
-60
1938.63
32.31
2
0.00
-1938.60
0.00


455
100
3514.00
35.14
3
0.00
-1938.60
3514.00


456
-300
300.00
1.00
1
-300.00
-1938.60
3514.00



fiddle
CREATE TABLE balance (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `amount` INTEGER,
  `foreignExchangeEquivalentTl` DECIMAL(10,2),
  `exchange rate` DECIMAL(10,2),
  `dovizID` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO balance
  (`id`, `amount`, `foreignExchangeEquivalentTl`, `exchange rate`, `dovizID` )
VALUES
  ('452', '-60', '1938.63', '32.31', '2'),
  ('455', '100', '3514.00', '35.14', '3'),
  ('456', '-300', '300', '1', '1');


Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


SELECT 
  `id`, `amount`
  , `exchange rate`, `dovizID`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN dovizID =1 THEN  `amount` * `exchange rate` ELSE 0  END) OVER (ORDER BY `id`) as  `TRY_balance`,
   SUM(CASE WHEN dovizID =2 THEN  `amount` * `exchange rate` ELSE 0 END ) OVER (ORDER BY `id`) AS `USD_balance`,
   SUM(CASE WHEN dovizID =3 THEN  `amount` * `exchange rate` ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY `id`) AS  `EUR_balance` 
  
  FROM balance




id
amount
exchange rate
dovizID
TRY_balance
USD_balance
EUR_balance




452
-60
32.31
2
0.00
-1938.60
0.00


455
100
35.14
3
0.00
-1938.60
3514.00


456
-300
1.00
1
-300.00
-1938.60
3514.00



fiddle
SELECT 
  `id`, `amount`
  , `exchange rate`, `dovizID`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN dovizID =1 THEN  `amount` * `exchange rate` ELSE 0  END) OVER (ORDER BY `id`) as  `TRY_balance`,
   SUM(CASE WHEN dovizID =2 THEN  `amount` * `exchange rate` ELSE 0 END ) OVER (ORDER BY `id`) AS `USD_balance`,
   SUM(CASE WHEN dovizID =3 THEN  `amount` * `exchange rate` ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY `id`) AS  `EUR_balance` 
  ,SUM(`amount` * `exchange rate`) OVER (ORDER BY `id`) as total_balance
  FROM balance




id
amount
exchange rate
dovizID
TRY_balance
USD_balance
EUR_balance
total_balance




452
-60
32.31
2
0.00
-1938.60
0.00
-1938.60


455
100
35.14
3
0.00
-1938.60
3514.00
1575.40


456
-300
1.00
1
-300.00
-1938.60
3514.00
1275.40



fiddle
the best that i can do
SELECT 
  `id`, `amount`
  , `exchange rate`, `dovizID`,
  CASE WHEN dovizID =1 THEN
  SUM(CASE WHEN dovizID =1 THEN  `amount` * `exchange rate` ELSE 0  END) OVER (ORDER BY `id`) ELSE 0 ENd  as  `TRY_balance`,
   CASE WHEN dovizID =2 THEN SUM(CASE WHEN dovizID =2 THEN  `amount` * `exchange rate` ELSE 0 END ) OVER (ORDER BY `id`) ELSE 0 ENd AS `USD_balance`,
   CASE WHEN dovizID =3 THEN SUM(CASE WHEN dovizID =3 THEN  `amount` * `exchange rate` ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY `id`) ELSE 0 END  AS  `EUR_balance` 
  ,SUM(`amount` * `exchange rate`) OVER (ORDER BY `id`) as total_balance
  FROM balance




id
amount
exchange rate
dovizID
TRY_balance
USD_balance
EUR_balance
total_balance




452
-60
32.31
2
0.00
-1938.60
0.00
-1938.60


455
100
35.14
3
0.00
0.00
3514.00
1575.40


456
-300
1.00
1
-300.00
0.00
0.00
1275.40



fiddle

This was not what I wanted, I stated it in the 2nd table above. I reached this conclusion through various queries.

that looks like the second taböe, if you don't need the columns remove them from the select

Any do you need a column TRY_balance at all or a usd when you only want the balnce of all

Yes, I need every milk, that's why I'm having problems.


In line 1, I owe 1938.6 TL, equivalent to -60 dollars.
In the 2nd line, I paid 3514 TL for 100 euros, so according to the balance status of the 2nd line, my debt should have been completed and 1575.4 TL should have become a creditor.
In the 3rd line, I owed 300 TL in return for -300 TL, and since I was credited with 1575.4 TL in the 2nd line, I should have become a creditor of 1275.4 TL.


The last line should be like this 1275.4 euros 0 tl $0

that is simple, but the other columns don't make sense, i added a total_balance

Thank you. This need is currently not met. I want to track the remaining balance of the current account in foreign currency. I will post a sample image when I get to the computer.

I added an image from a software I used as an example of what I want to do, can you help me?

This is so not possible in sql, but see my last try, that is so close as i can get

Thank you for the information. The program I took as an example made it, but I don't know which database they use. I will look for different solutions. So, can I create such a structure by changing the columns in the database or adding a new table?

no you take the last result and parse it row by row, if you need more columns simply ad them as you need, mysql support also CTE, where you can put the result of my query and then make calculations or add more information by joining ither tables. Please accept the answer
